# Power supply in parallel connection test

Tags: power-supply, power

I have 2 power supplies in parallel. Can I detect if they both are connected by only using the outputs and a multimeter. The power supplies have 24V 10A each.

This is what I figured:

Connect an electrical load that demands more than 10A of current. If the voltage drops of cuts off only one power supply is connected. Can this work and would it harm any device? This test will be executed 2 maybe 3 times. Thanks.

Comment: Connect each supply to the load via a current measurement shunt (something like an 0.01 ohm resistor). Then you can measure teh contribution of each PSU.

Comment: Sorry won't work. need to connect something to BOTH PSU's that's why it is quite a pickle.

Comment: Both are connected, each via its own shunt. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

With a real 10A supply you have no guarantee at what exact current the supply will cut off. Some supplies may be designed to supply brief surges well in excess of the maximum continuous current.

If this is a homework problem, consider that real wires are not zero resistance and even cheap voltmeters can detect typically +/-50uV DC on the 200mV (+/-199.9mV)scale. [AWG 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) wire has a resistance of about 4m\$\Omega\$ per foot.

Calculate what the minimum length of a sensible gauge of wire would be required to present a detectable voltage drop at the operating current using Ohm's law.

Comment: It is not a homework problem. I have access to 14A. I just need to be sure that both PSU's are connected. (It is merely a connection test)

Comment: It might work if the supplies reliably shut down quickly at 14A. Is that specified? Probably not. In keeping with my suggestions, you can detect voltage drop along wires from each output if it is actually supplying current. Again, it becomes dependent on the actual details of the supplies- do they share if paralleled or does one idle waiting for the other to fail?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you are interested in knowing if the supplies are 'connected' I'm interpreting that as knowing if they are supplying current to the load. If that's the case, you can insert a current shunt after each supply and sense the current from each supply.

Comment: "...to each supply..." No I can only insert something to BOTH PSU's. But at least thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPIIPi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Variations of the same idea.*

- Insert D1 and D2 from your power supplies to the common output.
- Wire an LED in reverse parallel with each and series resistor as shown on the top PSU.
- Power up one of the PSUs and check if the other LED lights. If not*, then rewire as shown in the lower example.

* The upper circuit might not work if there is no leakage path back through the PSU. The lower circuit provides a path to ground but if there's also a path through the PSU the LED may blow due to over-current. A combination of the two with two 2.4k resistors might be the best bet.

For remote monitoring replace the LEDs with opto-isolators, etc.

Comment: Nope, will not work sorry. Thanks for thinking with me, but it is not my schematic (testing) so cannot change the inside.